# How to get a cross tabulation with pandas crosstab that would display the frequency of multiple values of a column variable?

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

Let's say i have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5, size=(5,6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))
```

Crossing variables with `pd.crosstab` is simple enough:

```
table = pd.crosstab(index=df['A'], columns=df['B'])
```

Yields:

```
B  1  2  3  4
A            
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  1
2  0  1  1  0
3  0  1  0  0
```

Where I would for example want a table like this:

```
B  (1+2+3) 1  2  3  4
A            
0     1    1  0  0  0
1     0    0  0  0  1
2     2    0  1  1  0
3     1    0  1  0  0
```

Can anyone set me on the right track here?

Comment: There are good answers to be had. However, I'm struggling to understand what want. Simplify your example and show us what you expect to see.  That means you should manually calculate your self so we can see your logic.

Comment: I have updated my question, hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) with subset, but if use small random df there can be problem you get always another values so values of columns will be different. If use `np.random.seed(100)` get same test output as my answer.

```
table['(1+2+3)'] = table[[1,2,3]].sum(axis=1)
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5, size=(5,6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))
table = pd.crosstab(index=df['A'], columns=df['B'])
table['(1+2+3)'] = table[[1,2,3]].sum(axis=1)
print (table)
B  0  1  2  3  4  (1+2+3)
A                        
0  1  0  0  0  1        0
1  0  0  0  1  0        1
2  0  0  1  0  0        1
3  0  1  0  0  0        1
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!